# sort by month and year R

Tags: r, sorting, date, levels

I have grouped some data by month and year and am now plotting it. Does anyone know how to sort the month and years to the right order in an automated way so that it will work on any set of month and years (i.e. not give the levels manually).

Example data

```
df <-  data.frame(dates = c("01/2019", "02/2019", "07/2018", "09/2018", "10/2018", "11/2018", "12/2018"), values= c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Comment: You shouldn't have edited the closed question, you should unedit and instead ask a new question. Once a question has been closed as dupe people can't answer, unless you vote for reopen. :)

Comment: OK thanks for the info! I've made a new question